# Avidemux is no longer available in Ubuntu 18.04, what is an alternative?

Tags: 18.04, avidemux

The software avidemux seems to be no longer available in Ubuntu 18.04.

The command

```
sudo apt install avidemux
```

gives the prompt

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package avidemux is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'avidemux' has no installation candidate
```

So what is the GUI alternative of avidemux?